# How to define keys for switching to viewport left/right under Ubuntu 17.10 with Unity

Tags: unity, 17.10, compiz

Having issues with **Gnome** on Ubuntu 17.10 (high RAM usage, keyboard issues when changing focus to another window, Thunderbird loosing imap connection after sleep, delays, etc...), I decided to install **Unity** again,along with **Compiz**.

I no longer find in the settings of compiz how to define the key to switch to viewport left/right. Where did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about compiz-config-settings-manager and got to a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | grep --ignore-case switch
```

Which will give you a list of all the unity switch keys:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source ['<Super>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source-backward ['<Shift><Super>space']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-1 ['<Super>Home']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-2 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-3 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-4 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels ['<Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward ['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-5 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-8 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-9 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-6 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications ['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-10 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-11 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-12 ['disabled']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-last ['<Super>End']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group-backward ['<Shift><Super>Above_Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Alt>Right']
```

then use e.g.:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-7 '<Control><Alt>KP_Home'
```

to set 7 on the numeric keypad to switch to workspace 7.

`switch-to-workspace-right` and `switch-to-workspace-left` are the ones you're specifically looking for...

Comment: OK. I will remove my comment accordingly, since I can no longer edit it.

Comment: Next command helps to find all the keybindings: `gsettings list-recursively | grep '<Super>s'`